# What mean "Inf" in csv?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I am working on copying csv file content into postgresql database.
While copying into the database, I get this error:

> invalid input syntax for type numeric: "inf"

My question is:
I think "inf" means "infinitive" value, is it right? what does "inf" correctly mean? If it is kinda error, is it possible to recover original value?

And, Should I manually correct these values to copy it into the database?
Is there any good solution to fix this problem without manually correcting or setting exceptions in copying codebase?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but doesn't it mean "infinity"?

Comment: In  Python (which I see tagged in your question) `float("inf")` means infinity, so that could be where it came from. I wouldn't think there is an original value to recover.

Comment: Yeah, I think so, but not sure. Anyway, I need to convert it into correct value to import in the database.

Comment: "infinitive" means "the basic form of a verb, without an inflection binding it to a particular subject or tense" so it's unlikely to mean that in this context unless you're doing something with natural language processing.

Comment: @jss367- thanks for your response. I am importing it into the database. Every column will have its own data type, then How I can define the data type of this field?

Comment: it means the column expects a number (digits) but there is a string in that column (to be specific "inf") which is not number. you need to fix your export program so it doesn't create infinite values `(1/0)` in number column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inf` (meaning infinity) is a correct value for floating point values (`real` and `double precision`), but not for `numeric`.

So you will either have to use one of the former data types or fix the input data.